# Java streams to split and collect string to a Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a string like this

```
String input = "abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2";
```

I want to create a Map which looks like (after filtering out label3}
label1 -> {abc,xyz}
label2 -> {cde,pqr}
label3 -> {mno}

This is what I could do so far

```
  Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(inputString.split(" "))
                .filter(i -> !i.contains("label3"))
                .map(i -> i.split("//|"))
```

Also second use case:
how do I just collect the tokens all in one string

> abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2 => "abc cde xyz
>   mno pqr"

Comment: Counterintuitive to me to have value|key instead of key|value.  I agree completely with the suggestion to add a second delimiter between entries: key=value&key=value&...&key=value.  Split at ampersand and add pairs to a multi-map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First split the with space  as delimiter

```
input.split(" ") //[abc|label1, cde|label2, xyz|label1, mno|label3, pqr|label2]
```

And then split each string in array with pipe `\` as delimiter and use `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
                                      .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(str -> str[1], 
                                             Collectors.mapping(str -> str[0], Collectors.toList())));
```

**Output :**

```
{label1=[abc, xyz], label2=[cde, pqr], label3=[mno]}
```

Use `Collectors.joining` to collect value from `Map` into String

```
String result = map.values()
                   .stream()
                   .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. and how do I just collect the tokens all in one string

Comment: abc|label1 cde|label2 xyz|label1 mno|label3 pqr|label2 => "abc cde xyz mno pqr"

Comment: Just one more variation. How do I instead convert to {label1= abc xyz, label2=cde 
 pqr, label3=mno}